# Retrieving list of users in my Android App through Parse that match my Phone Contact List

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat

I am developing a Android Chat Messaging App Using Parse where I am saving user's phone number, username and password during the sign up process that I have completed successfully. Now I want to fetch the list of users already saved under the Phone Contact list matching their phone numbers and display the users in a list view. I am stuck of writing the Parse query and showing the fetched users in a list view.

**EDIT:**
I am trying to play around the following code, but clueless yet.

```
ParseUser user1 = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = user1.getQuery();
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("PhoneNumber", some_ph_no_from_my_contact);
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> numberList, ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(e == null){
            for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) 
            {
                // What to do here?
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("userId", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show some code to let us help you.

Comment: I have edited my query as per suggestion. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `OR` query:

```
public void getFriends(List<String> numbers) {
    List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseUser>>();
    for (String number : numbers) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("PhoneNumber", number);
        queries.add(parseQuery);
    }

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

    userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> numberList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) {
                    // What to do here?

                    //Use this list of ParseUser (numberList) in an ArrayAdapter
                    //or save it in a database
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`List<String> numbers` would be the list of phone numbers from the user's addressbook.

Once you have the `List<ParseUser>` just feed it to an `ArrayAdapter<ParseUser>` or save it in a local database, your choise (I'd go with the database).

Comment: Many thanks. I am trying this. For information, is there any option to call getQuery() only once for the whole list of phone numbers or I need to call it for every phone number in a loop as in this answer?

Comment: You have to add a new Query for every number, so I would think that getQuery() is necessary.
You could try with  ParseQuery<ParseUser> baseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery(); outside the for cycle, then inside  it use ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = baseQuery; but I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation that or query have. If your numbers list is longer than 10 elements it will be thrown Too many $or clauses exception. So you need to modify David's code little bit. If you have for example 80 elements in your numbers list, code will look like

```
public void getFriends(List<String> numbers) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i += 10) {

        List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = i; j < i + 10; j++) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            parseQuery.whereEqualTo("PhoneNumber", numbers.get(j));
            queries.add(parseQuery);
        }

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

        userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> numberList, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) {
                        // What to do here?

                        Log.e(TAG, numberList.get(i).getUsername());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```