# Finding which phone contacts are users in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my application, each user signs in with a phone number. In other words, each username corresponds to a different number. I want to detect which phone contacts are using this application in a way. However, I could not determine how should I do this. At first, I think about querying for each contact and get users_in_contacts by using an `OR` query at the end. This method is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503599/retrieving-list-of-users-in-my-android-app-through-parse-that-match-my-phone-con):

```
public void getFriends(List<String> numbers) {
    List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseUser>>();
    for (String number : numbers) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", number);
        queries.add(parseQuery);
    }

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

    userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> numberList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.v("" + i + ". user_contact", numberList.get(i).getUsername());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It is a working solution but I do not want to burst too many queries and exceed the limit of request per second. Thus, I want to know is there a better alternative or not.

In short, how can I achieve to find the users that are in contacts as fast and costless (with respect to request per second) as possible? I will be all ears to every advice and alternative ways comes from you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what about register a content provider observer? handle all contacts at startup, and then only handle contact changes in observer.

Comment: If a user with 1000 contacts signs up the system, 1000 queries that check user list will be performed in background. This will be just one time but still this value is too much. I should handle this with less queries than number of contracts. I am not sure the second method is better than first one in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a querying method named as .whereContainedIn() in Parse. By using this query, I can get users which are already in my contracts without using any other query. I put all of my contracts (which associated with a phone number) as parameter in this method and it worked. I wrote a AsyncTask to perform these operations and monitor the results in a ListView. If you give any advice to increase the performance of this task, I will appreciate it.

```
public class RetrieveContactedUsersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Activity activity;
    HashMap<String, String> contactsMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] contactedUserNumbers;
    ListView contactsView;


    public RetrieveContactedUsersTask (Activity activity, ListView contactsView) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.contactsView = contactsView;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        retrieveContactList();
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        TreeMap<String, String> contactedUsersMap = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < contactedUserNumbers.length; i++) {
            contactedUsersMap.put(contactsMap.get(contactedUserNumbers[i]), contactedUserNumbers[i]);
        }

        contactsView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(activity, contactedUsersMap));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

    public void retrieveContactList() {

        Cursor phones = null;

        try {
            phones = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
                String _number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                String _name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                contactsMap.put(_number, _name);
            }
            phones.close();

        } catch ( Exception e ) {}

        finally {
            if(phones != null){
                phones.close();
            }
        }

        try {
            retrieveContactedUsers(contactsMap);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void retrieveContactedUsers(Map<String, String> numbers) throws ParseException {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereContainedIn("username", numbers.keySet());

        List<ParseUser> users= query.find();
        contactedUserNumbers = new String[users.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            String value = users.get(i).getUsername();
            contactedUserNumbers[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: contactsView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(activity, contactedUsersMap)); i am having error in ContactAdapter class what should in write